# Get the value of other attribute in functional react component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to retrieve the attribute of the functional react component.

```
<DynamicComponentWithNoSSR mode="html" onChange={onHtmlChange} htmlCode={`<h1>dasdasd</h1>`}/>
```

get the value of htmlCode in onHtmlChange function.

```
const onHtmlChange = (e) =>{
            console.log(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `htmlCode` is already a part of your props.

```
const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = ({ onChange, htmlCode }) => {

   const onHtmlChange = () => {
      onChange(htmlCode) //return HTML back to your upper component
   }
   
   //whenever HTML code get updated, we call `onHtmlChange` to update `htmlCode`
   useEffect(() => {
     onHtmlChange() 
   }, [htmlCode])

   return <div>Whatever you want here</div>
}
```

Your upper component can be like this

```
const UpperComponent = () => {
    
   const onHtmlChange = (htmlCode) => {
     console.log(htmlCode);
   }   

   return <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR mode="html" onChange={onHtmlChange} htmlCode={`<h1>dasdasd</h1>`}/>
}
```

BUT I'm wondering one case, if `htmlCode` is already dynamic (not static value) in `UpperComponent`, you can access `htmlCode` value directly instead of via props of `DynamicComponentWithNoSSR`